# TLC5940 SOUT/SIN signal broken after 4th daisy-chained IC

Tags: led, pwm, shift-register, texas-instruments

I have a PCB with 5 TLC5940's daisy-chained. The first 4 work fine, but the fifth doesn't work. The LEDs connected to that one just go on at full brightness and that's it. When I measure the SOUT to SIN signals, they look fine up until the 4th TLC, but the signal coming out of the 4th one looks to be pulled up to VCC:

[image]

Channel 1 is showing SIN at the MCU, driving the first TLC with 3.3V logic, so that's why the bursts are a bit lower. Channel 2 is showing SOUT to SIN between TLC 4 and 5.

For reference, I've added an image showing SOUT/SIN between TLC no 3. and no.4:

[image]

There are no shorts between that line and any others, continuity tests between SOUT and SIN pins are fine. Any suggestions on how to possibly fix this?

Here's the layout (most of the LED section aren't included or blacked out), The MCU (on the left) is a Teensy board. So the SIN run from left to right. I have already checked if the strength of all the other signals like SCLK/GSCLK/XLAT/BLANK is ok by connecting the MCU on the right side headers. This shows identical behavior. The distance from left to right is about 40cm.

[image]

and a closeup between TLC 4 & 5:

[image]

Trace width is 4 mil, spacing is half the pin pitch of HTSSOP-28 (0.33 mm). This made it convenient to run all the tracks straight on the backside and connect with the smallest vias (0.3/0.45) to the TLC pins. Not sure if this was a good idea in hindsight :).

I have GND on layer 2 and all the empty space on 1 & 4. 5V plane on 3.

Comment: Can you add an image  of your layout? Does this still happen with the LEDs set to very low brightness?

Comment: Added some pictures. It also happens on very low brightness.

Comment: Is your  power supply rail holding up? That ramp down of logic voltage vs. time (or perhaps ramp up of ground voltage vs. time) is interesting.

Comment: I have 5V power entry on the left side of the board. Strangely when I measure board voltage, it's at 5.2V while the supply report 5.08 when not connected. I read about this somewhere yesterday, definetely a bit worrying.

I just took U5 off the board again but think I might have done something sloppy there. Now U1, U2 and U4 also stopped working. I might have still applied VCC to the TLCs with the logic powered down. Which notoriously breaks TLCs...

To clarify: I have the Teensy powered separately and the complete board off one 5V plane.

Comment: Replaced U1, U2, U4 and then added a new U5. Board is now fully functionial. Not sure what was the cause and if it is really resolved. I handed it over to the firmware people again, see if they can keep it in one piece ;)